# Como eu uso 2 drive mail no laravel em runtime?

Tags: laravel

Uma parte da minha aplicação, eu preciso usar o Sendgrid para enviar emails sujos  (marketing/boas vindas/esqueci a senha etc...) e outra parte da minha aplicação eu preciso usar Mailchimp (Campanhas) no caso mailchimp está funcionando mas como eu posso alterar uma chave e mudar drive em runtime?